# Case statement in the where clause SQL

Tags: sql

I have a parameter called `@Unit`.

I also have a unit column in my table. I Have other requirements so I need to do a case statement in the where clause.

```
CASE 
    WHEN @Unit > 0
    THEN unit = @Unit
END
```

The statement however is not accepting my `=`. I'm getting an error on `=`.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can **only** return a single, atomic value - you cannot use `CASE` as a flow control statement to do assignments inside of it

Comment: Your `CASE` expression results in a boolean value. While this is okay in standard SQL, not all DBMS support this. What is your DBMS? Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. Then you say "The statement however is not accepting my =". How do you know? Are you getting an error message? If so, why don't you show us the error message? Don't hide information from us that is supposed to help solve the issue.

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression has a result. Yours is `unit = @Unit` (or null in case @Unit is not greater than zero). Now, `unit = @Unit` is a boolean expression and its result is a boolean value (TRUE, FALSE or null). Not all DBMS, however, support a boolean datatype in their SQL dialect. Yours doesn't seem to accept it.

But why use a `CASE` expression at all? A `CASE` expression is used to evaluate a boolean expression (in your case `@Unit > 0`). But a `WHERE` clause already does this. For this reason it is rare we use `CASE` expressions in `WHERE`. We usually simply use `AND` and `OR` instead.

```
WHERE unit = @Unit OR (@Unit <= 0 OR @Unit IS NULL)
```

or

```
WHERE unit = @Unit OR COALESCE(@Unit, 0) <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unit = case when ISNULL(@Unit,0) > 0 then @Unit else unit end
```

this means if ISNULL(@Unit,0) has value, then use the unit = @Unit,
else unit = unit (the column of unit is equal to the column of unit)

Comment: Don't propose the usage of ISNULL, especially when no DB type has been taged. Standard functions like COALESCE should always be prefered since they don't depend on the DB.

Comment: Beware. This condition will remove rows where unit is null from the result, even if @Unit is not greater than zero.